# SassWarning: Deprecation $weight: Passing a number without unit % (100) is deprecated

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, sass, bootstrap-5

when I run the cmd command `webpack --mode production --color --progress` I get this message :

[image]

I use **Bootstrap v5.2.2** with **Sass v1.56.0**.

There is my full package.json

```
{
  "name": "xx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xx",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "xxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production --color --progress",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --color --devtool inline-source-map --hide-modules -w",
    "debug": "webpack --mode development --progress --color --devtool inline-source-map --debug --display-error-details --output-pathinfo --display-chunks -w",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "acorn": "^8.8.1",
    "ajv": "^8.11.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13"f,
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "bootstrap-input-spinner": "^3.1.13",
    "bourbon": "^7.2.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.10",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "bs-custom-file-input": "^1.3.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "expose-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "lighthouse": "^9.6.8",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "stylelint": "^14.14.1",
    "stylelint-checkstyle-formatter": "^0.1.2",
    "stylelint-config-twbs-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-remove-empty-scripts": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "browserslist": "^4.21.4",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001431",
    "card": "^2.5.4",
    "core-js": "^3.26.0",
    "iban": "0.0.14",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.19",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.0"
  },
  "old": {
    "lighthouse": "^5.1.0",
    "vanilla-lazyload": "^8.17.0"
  },
  "boutique": {
    "jquery.panzoom": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add **%** to this function on `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss 201:11` delete warning temporary.

This will be fixed with Bootstrap 5.2.3   https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/37425

```
@function opaque($background, $foreground) {
  @return mix(rgba($foreground, 1), $background, opacity($foreground) * 100%);
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5.2.3*

Comment: Thanks @user3615851 that helped a great deal, looks like 5.2.3 got released yesterday, so hopefully, no more errors on updated installs.

Comment: I am still getting this and have the following:
+-- bootstrap-scss@5.3.2
+-- bootstrap@5.3.2

It wouldn't have reverted, would it?

Answer (score 0):

I come cross same problem，and find the root cause，this is because the structure of mix($color-1,$color-2,$weight) function，and the third parameter is a number with unit（%）

please see here：
https://sparkbox.com/foundry/putting_the_fun_in_sass_color_functions